# Snapping an object in the center of two vertices

Tags: snapping

In some youtube videos i saw how they selected two vertices of two different objects to snap the object between the selected vertices. But the symbol on the snapping tool doesn't look like something that i have. Is this an addon?

And is there a possibility to achieve this effect: to place an object in the center of two selected vertices, without an addon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into *Edit Mode* of the object with the two vertices and select them.

Press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd> and snap *Cursor to Selected*. Tab out of *Edit Mode* and select the other object and press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd> and select *Selection to Cursor*.

[image: example]

Comment: To clarify that answer, you need to select both your objects in Object Mode (the cubes in the example). Then go into Edit Mode, select the two vertices on the cubes and CTRL-S > Cursor to Selected. Back into Object mode, select the Monkey head and CTRL-S > Selection to Cursor.